# Converting Array of Strings into Key Value Pair

Tags: javascript, foreach, array.prototype.map

I have an string from backend source, of format:

numbers: "1123763449056714753, 1123764853364097024, 1123770213739241473..."

I want to convert it into key-value pair something form so that I can map over these ids for my individual item div:

```
["numbers": [ 
              {"id":1123763449056714753 }, 
              {"id":1123764853364097024 },
              {"id":1123770213739241473 },
             ....
            ]
]
```

or

```
[                 {"id":1123763449056714753 }, 
                  {"id":1123764853364097024 },
                  {"id":1123770213739241473 },
                 ....

    ]
```

I tried using forEach()/ map() but gets error as undefined. Also I am not sure whether it is a collection of string or array of strings
Please help

Comment: considering the whole variable is string. Use `let obj = JSON.parse('{' +str+'}'); obj.numbers = obj.numbers.split(',').map(id => ({id}))`

Comment: Is the input a comma separated string or an array of strings as you mentioned in the title? Also, your output is invalid. Please post a valid input and expected outputs to create a [mcve]

Comment: `object.numbers = object.numbers.split(',').map(i => { id: +i }`. The question is quite unclear and doesn't hold the minimal amount of informations needed to verify the example. Please clarify it and **add what you've tried**.

Comment: Also, it's good to post the code that isn't quite working. That helps understand the original intent and give an answer that is more useful. (I agree with the two previous comments).

Comment: In the output, `id`is of type number. All these numbers are bigger than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`. So, when string converted to number, they won't be the same numbers anymore

Answer (score 3):

You could split the string and map the objects by keeping the strings (who are larger than allowed integer values).

```js
var object = { numbers: "1123763449056714753,1123764853364097024,1123770213739241473,1123771975162368003" },
    numbers = object.numbers.split(',').map(id => ({ id }));

console.log(numbers);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Isn't the id meant to be a numeric value (looking at his example)? Edit: NVM, you've fixed that already :P

Comment: FYI, the numbers are bigger than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`

Comment: @adiga nice catch, didn't notice that! So, technically, the "sample" output is somewhat invalid.

Answer (score 2):

You can `split` the object then `map` it and return the structure you want :

```js
const obj = {
  "numbers": "1123763449056714753,1123764853364097024,1123770213739241473,1123771975162368003..."
}


const res = {
  numbers: [
    obj.numbers.split(",").map(el => ({
      id: el
    }))
  ]
}

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could do is get the numbers as an array:

```js
var obj = {
  "numbers": "1123763449056714753,1123764853364097024,1123770213739241473,1123771975162368003"
};

var result = obj.numbers.split(',').reduce((acc, num) => {
  acc.push({ id: num });
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result)
```

or as @briosheje mentioned you could also use `map`:

```
var result = obj.numbers.split(',').map(num => ({id: num}));
```

The result would look like this:

```
[{"id":"1123763449056714753"},{"id":"1123764853364097024"},{"id":"1123770213739241473"},{"id":"1123771975162368003"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var arr = ["1123763449056714753","1123764853364097024","1123770213739241473","1123771975162368003"];
var newArr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var obj = {};
    obj.id = arr[i];
    newArr.push(obj);
}
console.log(newArr)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this.

```
var data = {"numbers":"1123763449056714753,1123764853364097024,1123770213739241473,1123771975162368003"};

data.numbers = data.numbers.split(',').reduce((res, id) => [...res, {id}], []);
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your data, you can just split the numbers string using "," and loop through it to perform the transform, like

```
var data = {"numbers":"1123763449056714753,1123764853364097024,1123770213739241473,1123771975162368003"};
var numbers_arr = data.numbers.split(",");
var result = {
  "numbers":[]
};
for(var i=0;i<numbers_arr.length;i++){
 var tempObj = {
    "id":parseInt(numbers_arr[i])
  };
  result.numbers.push(tempObj)
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```